# Given the Heliopause temps approach 30,000-50,000C does it seem possible humans can ever leave our Solar System?

Tags: interstellar-travel

Most rocks and elements are molten on earth before 10,000C correct?
Does that mean that nothing on earth could withstand the heliopause temperatures of 30,000-50,000C?  If this is correct, then:  would that then mean all hope of humans travelling "interstellar" is impossible?

Does this also mean that "Voyager" will melt soon?  Or, why not?
Is the hotter area outside our solar system a narrow area or very big, such as
it might be possible to travel through at high speed?
Just a few questions.....

Comment: Voyager 1 and 2 already traversed the heliopause without incident in 2012 and 2018 respectively.

Comment: Thank you, Triatticus.